# C# making web tester tool with HttpClient

Tags: c#, recaptcha, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a web tester tool with c#. I get HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable error or blocked recaptcha page after 50 requests on some sites. Is there a way not to take these mistakes ?

```
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();            
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true,
            UseCookies = true,
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        });

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DNT", "1");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TE", "Trailers");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.example.com/");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "www.example.com/");
```

Comment: It's probably nothing you're doing, it's the server you're targeting mitigating too frequent a requests in order to avoid things like DOS.

Comment: Websites with captcha statements are designed specifically to prevent users performing automated tasks because they want real users hitting there website.
You wouldn't be up to mischief would you?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a proxy rotation service that'll rotate your call among a list of different ip addresses so your request doesn't get blocked by rate limiter. There are many legitimate use cases for this such as web scraping, price monitoring, ad verification, etc. Google around for both free and paid services